# FindBy: How + using vs. name of location strategy

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, annotations, webdriver, findby

Using Selenium WebDriver,

when annotating your Locators with [@FindBy](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html) you can choose between a combination of How + using:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

or you can directly use the location strategy like so:

```
@FindBy(id = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

I always use the way shorter second version.

I cannot think of any reason why I should use the longer How+using version.

So my question is:

**Are there situations where you need to use [How + using]?**

**If not, why does this longer version even exist?**

Answer (score 1):

Greetings and salutations,

If you heard of `@FindBy(how=How.CSS , using="locator")` you probably want to learn how to manipulate all `driver.findElement(By)` REST calls.
Selenium based on REST calls the assure if a so called `WebElement` object is exists within the DOM.
We can always user `@FindBy(id="localtor")` which basically say,
'Hey, ima execute a REST call specificly for this HTML tag by `id` as `key` and `locator` as value.

With that said,

working with `@FindBy( how=How.CSS, using="locator" )` enable to us a whole different gameplay...
Meet `@CacheLookup` , 
it will help you use the Browser Cache System to locate everything from the Browser Cache Storage, brings with it lots of performance (about 50% off REST calls runtime )

You can read more here:
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/cachelookup-in-pageobjectmodel/

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a search on documentation available but could not find the reason why How + Using way of annotating with @FindBy is used when we can use the name of location strategy directly.

If you look at the way documentation is written in comments [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.java?r=fd7711ae49e90288117c44f659f9848273e9705d):

> You can either use this annotation by specifying both "how" and "using" or by specifying one of the location strategies (eg: "id") with an appropriate value to use. Both options will delegate down to the matching By methods in By class.

**There seems to be no doubt that what How+Using can do, the same can be done using the name of location strategy.**

Now, why both are there and can the longer version be better left off, there seems to be no direct mention as of now. You can add a query in [Selenium community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users) if you want.